# React native app crashes on slow Android devices when scheduling over 200 local notifications

Tags: javascript, android, push-notification, react-native

I am scheduling over 200 notifications on an Android application in a simple loop using [this package](https://github.com/zo0r/react-native-push-notification).

When doing so, emulators and high-end devices don't crash, but low-end devices crash only on Release mode, leaving no trace of the error except "Unfortunately, %appName% has stopped.".

```
for (let i = 0; i < 200; i++) {
    PushNotification.localNotificationSchedule(event);
}
```

I already tried adding a throttle to the loop with a `setTimeout`, to ease the load on the processor but the app keeps crashing.
Sometimes after the crash 100 notifications have been scheduled, sometimes all of them, sometimes none and sometimes it doesn't crash.

Comment: Can you add crash log?

Comment: Why are you scheduling so many notifications?

Comment: I'm not related to this project anymore and didn't have much time at the time to find a solution. Crash logs showed a message indicating that a limit on scheduled notifications had been reached. What we eventually did was redesign the functionality to only use repeated notifications and that way we kept the notification numbers lower.